# How do I implement synchronously waiting for a callback in Python 3 asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Due to some unusual constraints, I need to synchronously wait for a callback URL from another service before returning a response. Currently I have something resembling:

```
ROUTE = '/operation'
async def post(self):
    ##SOME OPERATIONS##
    post_body = { 'callbackUrl' : 'myservice.com/cb' }
    response = await other_service.post('/endpoint')
    global my_return_value
    my_return_value = None
    while not my_return_value:
        pass
    return self.make_response(my_return_value)
```

Then I have a way to handle the callback URL something like:

```
ROUTE = '/cb'
async def post(self):
    ##OPERATIONS###
    global my_return_value
    my_return_value = some_value
    return web.json_response()
```

The problem with this code is that it forever gets trapped in that while loop forever even if the callback URL gets invoked. I suspect there is a better way to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about it nor how to google for it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this, but I think your immediate problem is that you're missing a `global my_return_value` in the callback route.

Comment: So why not have `other_service.post()` return a `(some_value, web.json_response())` tuple?

Comment: And you get an infinite loop because you set `my_return_value = None` after calling the post. Your co-routines are *still sequential*, the `/operation` `post()` co-routine won't continue until the `response = await other_service.post('/endpoint')` returns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe that the `other_service.post(...)` call is making an HTTP request (and then returning), while the callback isn't invoked until that other service turns around and makes an HTTP request back to us.

Comment: @smarx that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick scan, but I think you're trapped in

```
while not my_return_value:
    pass
```

Python will be trapped there and not have time to deal with the callback function. What you need is

```
while not my_return_value:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

(or you can even do an `asyncio.sleep(0)` if you don't want the millisecond delay).

An even nicer way would be (and now I'm writing from memory, no guarantees...):

```
my_return_value = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
await my_return_value
return self.make_response(my_return_value.result())


async def post(self):
    ##OPERATIONS###
    my_return_value.set_result(some_value)
    return web.json_response()
```

Note however that either way will break very much if there is ever more than one concurrent use of this system. It feels very fragile! Maybe even better:

```
ROUTE = '/operation'
my_return_value = {}

async def post(self):
    ##SOME OPERATIONS##
    token = "%016x" % random.SystemRandom().randint(0, 2**128)
    post_body = { 'callbackUrl' : 'myservice.com/cb?token='+token }
    response = await other_service.post('/endpoint')
    my_return_value[token] = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
    await my_return_value[token]
    result = my_return_value[token].result()
    del my_return_value[token]
    return self.make_response(result)

async def post(self):
    ##OPERATIONS###
    token = self.arguments("token")
    my_return_value[token].set_result(some_value)
    return web.json_response()
```

Now cherry on top would be a timer that would cancel the future after a timeout and clean up the entry in `my_return_value` after a while if the callback does not happen. Also, if you're going with my last suggestion, don't call it `my_return_value` but something like `callback_future_by_token`...

Comment: My current solution looks something like your second except with a uuid in place of the random number generation. I am not as confident in my use of Futures, though, so this is particularly helpful.